# jdbc foreign key constraint

Tags: java, mysql

I am creating a java application and I have connected to mysql database. I tried creating a table with foreign key and I got error `Cannot add foreign key constraint` below are my tables

```
execute("CREATE TABLE " + BBBBB + "("
                        + "         id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n"
                        + "         consultantID varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         name varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         gender varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         age varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         email varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         mobile varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         address varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         PRIMARY KEY (id)"
                        + ")        ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1"
                );


execute("CREATE TABLE " + AAAAA + "("
                        + "         id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n"
                        + "         patientID varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         name varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         gender varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         age varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         insurance varchar(225),\n"
                        + "         mobile varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         address varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         PRIMARY KEY (id)"
                        + ")        ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1"
                );

execute("CREATE TABLE " + CCCCC + "("
                        + "         id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,\n"
                        + "         patientID varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         consultantID varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         time varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         date varchar(225) NOT NULL,\n"
                        + "         renewCount INTEGER default 0,\n"
                        + "         FOREIGN KEY (patientID) REFERENCES AAAAA(pID),\n"
                        + "         FOREIGN KEY (consultantID) REFERENCES BBBBB(cID),\n"
                        + "         PRIMARY KEY (id)"
                        + ")        ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1"
```

I got an error as stated above. additional codes would be added on request. Thanks

Comment: what is `BBBBB` and `AAAAA`? One time you use them as variables, one time those Strings are fixed in the creation of `CCCCC`

Comment: They are the table names

Comment: `String TABLE_NAME = "APPOINTMENTS"`

Comment: We don't care about the TABLE_NAME variable. It's not used anywere. We're asking you about the variables BBBBB and AAAAA (which are horribly named, BTW).

Comment: Okay, so you needlessly obfuscated your code, NOT recommended. Because if `AAAAA` is actually `"APPOINTMENTS"` that code does not work since `CCCCC` still tries to create a foreign key constraint on the table literally named "AAAAA".

Comment: I used the AAAAA ... to reference the FOREIGN keys involved.

Comment: It's quite a simple question: what is the value stored in the variable AAAAA. Same question for the variable BBBBB. Why don't you answer these two extremely simple questions?

Comment: they are just table names.

Comment: But the name matters. If you name a table foobar, and then try to create another table with a foreign key to the table helloworld, that won't work, because the table is not named helloworld, but foobar. Don't you realize this? Again, for the fifth time, what is the value of the variables AAAAA and BBBBB?

Comment: Please post the ACTUAL code you have, do NOT try to obfuscate the code by using `AAAAA`, `BBBBB` and `CCCCC`, that only confuses everybody, makes error message unreadable and does not give you anything.

Answer (score 4):

1. in the third statement, `pID` and `cID` don't seem to exist, they should be `patientID` and `consultantID`
2. to create the tables you are using the variables `AAAAA` and `BBBBB`, but in the third statement you are referring to them as the string constants "AAAAA" and "BBBBB", which might not be correct, you should always use the variables, for example:

   ```
   " ... REFERENCES " + BBBBB + "(cID) ... "
   ```